# Ifi read surah Al Mulk and Ayatul Kursi, night dhikr and surah Ikhlas,Nas and Felek before sleeping but then I go to toilet should i read them again

Tags: dua, dhikr, surah

Because Sometimes I nees to go to toilet before sleeping and then iam too sleepy to read all the suras again does it count if i read it just once?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. What is your concern? And why should you repeat them and what is the issue if you repeated it?